# how to call a sub function only once within an periodically function call

Tags: c

I'm beginner with c and have a simple question:

I have a function *myfunction()* which is called periodically every 100 ms.
Within this function I have to call an other function but only once at the first call at beginn of *myfunction()*, but no periodically.

```
void myfunction() // function is called periodically every 100 ms
{
    ...
    mySubfunction(); // this function have to be called only once in the  first call of myFunction() and than skipped each time after that.
}   ...
```

How to realize this in c?

Comment: If `mySubfunction` in general is not supposed be called when `myfunction` is called, then `mySubfunction` shouldn't be part of `myfunction`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `static`? Something along the lines of

```
void myfunction() // function is called periodically every 100 ms
{
    static int once = 1;
    if (once) {
        mySubfunction(); 
        once = 0;
    }
}
```

The variable `once` in the example will be initalized only once and retain its value between invocations because of `static` keyword.

Be aware of implications in multithreaded environment, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15857732/5899161).

Answer (score 0):

you can have something like

```
static int flag = 1
void myfunction() // function is called periodically every 100 ms
{
    if(flag)
    {
       mySubfunction(); 
       flag = 0;
    }     
 }
```

...

Answer (score 0):

on first look task is very simply, can be next code:

```
void func()
{
    static LONG first = TRUE;
    if (_InterlockedExchange(&first, FALSE))
    {
        subfunc();
    }
    // some code
}
```

this give 100% guarantee that  `subfunc()` will be called once and only once even if several thread in concurrent call your `func()`

but what be if `// some code` depended on result of `subfunc` ? in this case task become already not trivial. need some synchronization. and here already depended from os or compiler. in Windows, begin from Vista understand this problem and add function [`InitOnceExecuteOnce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683493(v=vs.85).aspx) - read [Using One-Time Initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686934(v=vs.85).aspx)
if your `subfunc()` have no *in* and *out* parameters code can be very simply:

```
BOOL CALLBACK InitOnceCallback(PINIT_ONCE /*InitOnce*/, PVOID /*Parameter*/,PVOID* /*Context*/)
{
    subfunc();
    return TRUE;
}

void func()
{
    static INIT_ONCE once = RTL_RUN_ONCE_INIT;
    if (InitOnceExecuteOnce(&once, InitOnceCallback, 0, 0))
    {
        // somecode
    }
    // error init
}
```

also some modern compilers can correct handle static one time initialization. say latest versions of `CL`. with it code can be next:

```
void func()
{
    static char tag = (subfunc(), 0);
    // some code
}
```

here `CL` internally call special functions (implemented in *CRT*) `_Init_thread_header`, `_Init_thread_footer` - implementation can be look in crt source code - `thread_safe_statics.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

This may be more advanced than you're looking for, but you could use function pointers and change which function gets called.

```
// Function declarations
void mySubfunction(void);
void myNormalfunction(void);

// Function pointer, which can be changed at run time.
static void (*myfunction)(void) = mySubfunction;

void mySubfunction(void)
{
    // Do the sub-function stuff.

    // Change the function pointer to the normal function.
    myfunction = myNormalfunction();

    // Do the normal function stuff (if necessary on the first call).
    myNormalfunction();
}

void myNormalfunction(void)
{
    // Etc.
}

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        // Call myfunction as you usually would.
        myfunction();
    }
    return 0;
}
```